# Name of a particular kind of measures

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Is there any particular name given to measures $\mu$ for which there exists $g\in\mathbb{L}^1(\mathbb{R}^p,\lambda)$ such that
$$\forall A\in\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}^p)\quad\mu(A)=\int_Ag \,\mathrm{d}\lambda~?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every such measure is absolutely continuous w.r.t $\lambda$.  If $\lambda$ is $\sigma$-finite, then the Radon-Nikodym theorem says that all measures that are absolutely continuous w.r.t. $\lambda$ are of this form.

EDIT: In light of the comment below, perhaps "measure with density" is more appropriate for the name.  The absolute continuity is correct, though.

Comment: So it's as if your answer to "What is the name?" is that it is "absolutely continuous measures (w.r.t. $\lambda$)." But if I'm not mistaken the $\sigma$-finiteness condition is quite a substantial thing and you don't need any sort of exotic spaces to find cases where it doesn't hold.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Fair point.  Perhaps "measure with density" is a better choice for the name.